# Build gdb from sources with Python support on Windows with MinGW (from MSYS2)

Tags: python, gdb, mingw, msys2

I tried to build GDB from sources including Python support. It works properly on Linux but on Windows it is not working. The build is unable to find python properly.

I use Mingw32 shell from MSYS2 installed from https://www.msys2.org/.

I already tried with Python installed the following ways:

- Install Python via `pacman -S python` and run configure script with `--with-python` -> failed
- Install Python via `pacboy -S python` and run configure script with `--with-python` -> failed
- run configure script with `--with-python=python3` -> failed
- Install Python3 local on Windows and provide path - run configure script with `--with-python=/path/to/python3` -> failed

The build ends with the message `configure: error: python is missing or unusable`.

Can anyone guide me how to install python properly?

Comment: In the config.log there is usually more info why python is missing/unusable.

Comment: You will need a Python that comes with a .dll file and also the .a (or .dll.a) library file and the use `-L` to point the linker to the location of the library file.

Comment: Which [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/)? Assuming `MINGW64`, you probably want `mingw-w64-x86_64-python`, not `python`.

Comment: If you are interested in a prebuilt version I already did the work and the latest downloads on https://winlibs.com/ contain GDB with Python support.